# ArcGIS Javascript Api centerAt

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Trying to center the map at a certain coordinates but map only centers at 0,0 instead. Coordinates are in decimal degrees. Code below.

```
function foo(data) {

        var lon = data.address.longitude;
        var lat = data.address.latitude;
        var coord = [lat,lon];

        var point = new esri.geometry.Point(coord) 

        console.log(point)

        map.centerAt(point);
    };
```

Comment: possible that your map is displaying in web mercator (aka google projection) and lat/lon need projecting before you `centerAt`

Comment: Even when I give a spatial reference like so it still does not pan to the correct location.                                                       var point = new esri.geometry.Point(coord, 102100)

Comment: You'll have to project the point to Web Mercator using the built-in tool [geographicToWebMercator](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html#geographictowebmercator).

Comment: If you're not using web mercator, make sure it matches whatever coordinate system you assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im going to have to disagree with everyone in the comments.

if @mdown 's application loads web mercator tiles, he can pass a long/lat pair to `map.centerAt()` and skip declaring the spatial reference entirely because the API assumes WGS84 when nothing else is specified (docced [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/point-amd.html#point1)) and is able to reproject the values appropriately on the fly.

http://jsbin.com/yogugecago/edit?html,output

in the code sample above, he's passing longitude and latitude in the wrong order.